# multiplying int with double in C#

Tags: c#, int, double

I have a problem, when I´m trying to multiply int by double.
int are baseSalary and employeeSapary (this is int array) and 
commission is double constant = .09
I need to get employeeSalaries in int but keep getting a problem saying that i cant multiply int with double. I tried to convert double to int but in that case the eployeeSalary will always be baseSalary because commission will always be 0 (s*commission)=0 
How can I get valid score for employeeSalaries?
Thank you!

```
private int CalculateAndStoreSalary(int s, int i)

        {
            int.TryParse(txtSales.Text, out s);
            employeeSalaries[i] = baseSalary + (s * commission);          
            return employeeSalaries[i];
        }
```

Comment: For currency, you should use `decimal` to avoid rounding errors.

Comment: Cast the whole expression to int after multiplication.

Comment: I know but this is a assignment and professor told us to use A double representing the percent of sales that is given as commission (.09).And to declare it as a class(instance) variable

Comment: I dont know how to cast I just started with c#. I now that Iam placing double into in int but how can I calculate employeeSalaries then?

Comment: Just as a side note, I'd highly recommend that you give a meaningful name for the parameters. Instead of `(int s, int i)`, I'd recommend something like `(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)` for example... You can use better names of course.

Comment: firstNumber is just as meaningless as i, isn't it?

Comment: Having `s` as a parameter at all is useless here, since you immediately overwrite any value the caller passes in.

Comment: Are you sure that your professor didn't also want you to store salary as a double in that case? Also, `s` shouldn't be a parameter, but instead a local variable. Also, don't parse the textbox value inside that method. Parse it somewhere outside and pass it as a parameter to the method.

Comment: This helped employeeSalaries[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(baseSalary + (s * commission), 0));  But since Iam just a beginner i would never think of that :D

Comment: Groo salary is int i saw on examples that prof gave us. On that examples the total salary is rounded as a int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can round it, and assign it as:

```
employeeSalaries[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(baseSalary + (s * commission), 0));
```

It may not be exact, but something like that should do the trick, where you round it to the nearest zero (or use Floor or Ceiling to round down/up always), and then convert it to an integer on assignment.